# Rotate last n elements of array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to implement a function that deletes a character from a string wherever the current index is. Below is a skeleton of what I have so far. I'm trying to rotate the character I want to remove to the end of the string then replace it with a null terminator. The code I have below does not seem to actually rotate buffer because the output I'm getting is "wor" instead of the expected output "wrd".

```
int main() {
    char buffer[]="word";
    int currIndex=2;
    int endIndex=strlen(buffer);
    currIndex--;
    endIndex--;

    rotate(buffer+currIndex,
        buffer+1,
        buffer+strlen(buffer));
    buffer[endIndex]='\0';
    cout << buffer << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string`?

Comment: I do not exactly understand your explanation. Let's say you would like to rotate in `abcdef` at character `e`. The expected output is than `efabcd`? Am I right?

Comment: @ovanes with your input I would expect to get `abcdfe` returned from the rotate call then a final output of `abcdf` after setting the last index to the null terminator.

Comment: Note, that the expected output is `wod`, not `wrd`. Array indices are zero-based in C++.

Comment: @IInspectable yes I think I did a poor job of explaining exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to get functionality similar to how backspace functions in a Unix environment. I am doing this by decrementing `currIndex` before rotating rather than after. I am also checking to make sure I don't have `currIndex < 0` in my actual code.

Comment: strmove (buffer+currIndex, buffer+currIndex+1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a std::string makes things way easier because I don't have to think about pointers:

```
std::string buffer="word";
rotate(buffer.begin()+1, buffer.begin()+2, buffer.end());
buffer.resize(buffer.size()-1);
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4IFsRoi9C48565lt)

Alternatively, we can stick with a c-style array:

```
char buffer[]="word";
rotate(buffer+1, buffer+2, buffer+4);
buffer[3] = '\0';
```

[Demo2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KOyHSXlL1ydxIwCC)

---

[`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) accepts 3 arguments:

```
template< class ForwardIt >
ForwardIt rotate( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt n_first, ForwardIt last );
```

`first` is the first element in the range you want to left rotate.

`nfirst` is the element you want to be at the start of the range after you've rotated (this tells the algorithm how many times to left rotate, effectively)

`last` is the last element in the range you want to rotate.

Your code:

```
char buffer[]="word";
int currIndex=2;
int endIndex=strlen(buffer);
currIndex--;
endIndex--;
rotate(buffer+currIndex,
    buffer+1,
    buffer+strlen(buffer));
buffer[endIndex]='\0';
```

Was actually really close. You just got the second argument wrong. It should have been

```
rotate(buffer+currIndex,
    buffer+2,
    buffer+strlen(buffer));
buffer[endIndex]='\0';
```

But the code was admittedly a bit confusing written with the increments and decrements.

Comment: I believe the entire rotating characters around is just part of the OP's proposed solution to their problem. The actual solution would be [std::string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

Comment: Thank you! The solution more generally: `rotate(buffer+currIndex,buffer+currIndex+1,buffer+strlen(buffer));`

Comment: @IInspectable: That makes a stupid amount of sense. Way to think outside the box! (Post that as an answer and you've got a guaranteed upvote from me)

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't attempt to answer the question being asked, but rather solve the underlying problem: Removing a single character from a string.

The solution is a simple application of the [std::string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) class member:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string word{ "word" };
    std::string::size_type currIndex{ 2 };
    word.erase( currIndex, 1 );
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
}
```